# Drupal variable_set when resetting module admin form values

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-fapi

I am trying to do a variable_set() when clicking 'Reset default values' on my module's admin page form. This runs through system_settings_form_submit(). The #default_value inside my form is reset, but my module relies on this stored variable to display some data. Clicking reset fills in the form with the default, but does not 'Save' it to recreate the variable in the database, so my module's function breaks. It appears that nothing happens after clicking Reset, other than it deleting the variable from the database. Thanks in advance.

My submit function looks like this:

```
function faculty_submit(&$form, &$form_state){
  if($form_state['values']['op'] == 'Reset to defaults') {
    global $faculty_detail_template_default;
    variable_set('faculty_detail_template', $faculty_detail_template_default);
  }
  elseif ($form_state['values']['op'] == 'Save configuration') {
  // Clear caches for list and detail pages.
  cache_clear_all('faculty_list', 'cache', TRUE);
  cache_clear_all('faculty_detail_load', 'cache', TRUE);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all that's what [`system_settings_form_submit`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module/function/system_settings_form_submit/6/) does when you press the **Reset to defaults** button. It calls `variable_del` which will delete **all** your defined variables in the form from the `variables` table.

Now your form's `#default` value is probably filled because you do something like this:

```
global $faculty_detail_template_default;
$form = array (
  '#default_value' => variable_get('faculty_detail_template', $faculty_detail_template_default),
);
```

I don't see why you insist of adding a default value in the `variables` table. This entire approach is flawed. Just use `variable_get($name, $default)` wherever your code depends on `faculty_detail_template`. That's precisely what  the second parameter of this function is used for: `$default The default value to use if this variable has never been set.` So for Drupal, the absence of a variable from the `variable` table means it's up to the coder how to handle this case (provide a default for example). Default value which is specified using `variable_get`.

Second, if you used `system_settings_form` then you already have a submit function, the one mentioned above (`system_settings_form_submit`) so your `faculty_submit` won't be called unless you add it specifically to the array of submit callbacks to be executed. Something like this:

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'faculty_submit';
return system_settings_form($form);
```

BTW, using global variables is a bad idea (in general) and you should try to avoid using them. That's what variables are used for :) Pieces of information which can be retrieved in different parts of the code. So instead add a [`.install`](http://drupal.org/node/323314) file to your module and in that file you define these *global variables* using `variable_set`. This is a lot cleaner than just magically popping some global variables in the middle of the code.

Comment: Max, thanks for your thorough response. The reason I am setting a default is that I am providing a 'template' for some output that is editable by the user (similar to the Content Templates) module. I want the module to come with a default out of the box, and be able to always reset to that default in case a user changes the output to something they don't like.

I also do have a submit function that is defined just the way you wrote it.

Comment: Just to follow up, I can't figure out a way that when a user clicks to "Reset to defaults", to fill the template field back in with the content from my variable. The data of that variable is what is being used to output pages in my module, so when that variable gets deleted and not reinstated with the variable_set, the pages are blank until I re-save the form.

Comment: Don't mention it, I hope it helps you. Can you post the entire form (with validation and submit functions) and tell me what field gets empty after the `Reset to defaults` button is pressed? That way I can have a better understanding of what goes on.

Comment: Below is the code for the admin form for my module. The `faculty_detail_template` variable in the variables table gets emptied. You can see in my submit function that I am trying to set this if it isn't there, but this all seems to happen before `system_settings_form_submit` happens. Thanks.

http://pastie.org/2898559

Comment: OK, problem was that your custom submit function gets called before the system_settings_form_submit where the variables get deleted. So we need to change the order, to make sure the custom submit gets called last. Short version like this: `$form = system_settings_form($form); $form['#submit'][] = 'faculty_submit';` Here's a rewritten version of your code http://pastie.org/2906352. It eliminates the need for global variables and also let Drupal do some of the hard work, like generating list items. Try to think in a Drupal way, not in a PHP way. Made the same mistakes myself :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use &$form_state['values']['yourVariableNameOfForm'] instead of what I have made bold below.

variable_set('faculty_detail_template', **$faculty_detail_template_default**);

Comment: `faculty_detail_template_default` is a global variable...it doesn't come from the form submission

Comment: then maybe just pass the address &$faculty_detail_template_default instead of passing the variable

Comment: The $faculty_detail_template_default variable is just inside my faculty.admin.inc file. I made it global so I could call it into a few different functions.

Comment: try to add & and see it it works maybe variable_set will only take a reference

Comment: The variable_set() never occurs because the variable is gone from the variables table in the database, not stood up with a blank value.